# Trying to download file from FTP results in an "500 Illegal PORT command" error

Tags: ruby, ftp, download

If I execute this locally, everything works fine:

```
require 'net/ftp'

ftp=Net::FTP.new("myftpserver.com", "username", "password")

ftp.getbinaryfile("/myfile.zip","localfile.zip")
ftp.close
```

If I attempt to execute it on the Linux server I am using, the result is:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:273:in `getresp': 500 Illegal
PORT command. (Net::FTPPermError)   from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:281:in `voidresp'  from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:304:in `block in voidcmd'  from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'   from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:302:in `voidcmd'   from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:317:in `sendport'  from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:325:in `makeport'  from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:358:in `transfercmd'   from
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:420:in `block (2 levels) in
retrbinary'   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:166:in
`with_binary'   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:419:in `block
in retrbinary'  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in
`mon_synchronize'   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:418:in
`retrbinary'  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:539:in
`getbinaryfile'
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: possibly should be moved to serverfault..

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I found the answer at http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/161274:

> Beyond firewalls, active ftp won't work behind a NAT device. Ftp
>   servers sometimes say illegal port command if you tell them that your
>   address is a private ip address like 192.168.x (your address on the
>   network behind the nat device)

Adding:

```
ftp.passive = true
```

fixed it.

Comment: +1 ... I get the same error in Netbeans Remote Editor, Fixed by changing to passive mode.

Comment: i have used this gem "paperclip-storage-ftp" and i am getting error like Net::FTPPermError 500 while uploading photo . so can you tell me where i should put this line         ftp.passive = true  in model?? you can see this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540851/getting-random-error-while-upload-photo-with-paperclip-on-my-ftp-server